# How to print only outerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I want to print outerHTML only and not innerHTML. How can I achieve this?

Sample HTML:

```
<div id="one">
    <div id="two">
        <div id="three">
            <div id="four">
            <div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Desired outout:

```
<div id="two"></div>
```

I tried using outerHTML but it returns me

```
<div id="two">
    <div id="three">
        <div id="four">
        <div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If I try to remove innerHTML, it affects DOM

EDIT I tried this 
    $('#two').clone().html('')[0]

it returns me the result but is it right way?

Comment: The HTML you wish to retrieve technically doesn't exist. So you'd have to manipulate it in order to retrieve it the way you want to. Hint: Clone the element, set its innerHTML to empty and then retrieve the outerHTML

Answer (score 2):

```
    function outerHTML(id){
       var clone = document.getElementById(id).cloneNode();
       clone.innerHTML = "";
       return clone.outerHTML;
    }

    //usage
    outerHTML("one");
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/6V34p/1

Comment: What is teh difference between clone() and cloneNode()?

Comment: clone() is jQuery, whereas cloneNode() is vanilla js :)

Comment: `clone` is a function in the jQuery library, while `cloneNode` is a function in native JS.

Answer (score 1):

```
alert(document.getElementById("one").outerHTML.replace(c.innerHTML,""));
```

Comment: No, it just return the value, you can use it as var outer = document.getElementById("one").outerHTML.replace(c.innerHTML,"") for instance

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you're after, but have you try something like this.

```
<div class="divName">
    <div id="123">
       <p>HelloWorld</p>
    </div>
    <div id="456">
       <p>Not Here</p>
   </div>
</div>


var alert = $('#123').clone().wrap('<div></div>').parent().html();
alert(alert);
```

Answer (score 0):

Unsing outerHTML will always display the tag and all it child elements.

```
<div id="two">
    <div id="three">
        <div id="four">
        <div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The best way is to first use outerHTML and then hide the child element using jquery.